# Angular-Cli limpiar cache

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0, angular-cli

Estoy haciendo cambios en un proyecto generado con angular-cli pero al parecer quedo colgado algun archivo en cache y node no se da cuenta y me sigue enviando un mensaje de error

`ERROR in D:/Workspace/NodeJs/TrackEditor/src/app/pages/pages/pages.component.ts (6,5): Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; stylesUrl: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'. 
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'stylesUrl' does not exist in type 'Component'.
webpack: Failed to compile.`

corregí el pages.component.ts pero no me toma los cambios.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pages',
    templateUrl: './pages.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pages.css']
})
export class PagesComponent {}
```

alguna forma de limpiar la cache y recompilar el proyecto.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me ha sucedido que el webpack no reconoce ciertos cambios, por lo que es recomendable que canceles la ejecución del proyecto y vuelvas a user `ng serve` o `npm start` según tu hayas decidido correrlo por las necesidades del mismo.

En caso de seguir con problemas vuelve a correr `npm install` para actualizar la carpeta de **node_modules**.

Sí en verdad necesitas limpiar la caché, utiliza el siguiente comando: 
`npm cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

El problema que se muestra ahí es un problema de angular-cli y no de NodeJs, no sé si el código del componente fue generado desde el terminal o fue escrito manualmente, si fue escrito manualmente, elimine la carpeta y ejecute el comando **ng generate component (nombre del componente)** que en este caso sería pagescomponent.

Answer (score 0):

O tienes mal la información del nuevo componente en el '**app.module.ts**' o alguno de los ficheros que has puesto bajo '@Component' (selector, templateUrl o styleUrls) no existen.

Lo más normal es lo primero, el nombre de la clase, la ruta dónde se encuentra o el nombre del fichero no están correctamente indicados en el 'app.module.ts'.